# AR VR видео в android

Tags: android, анимация, видео, ar, vr

[Как сделать такое в андроид?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pjrl3ORqXM)

Если бы дело было 2D плоскости, то ясно как это бы работало. Но в данном случае, мне не ясно логика работы данной фишки. с 3D моделью опять таки понятно, нарисовали такую и ты вставляешь в  приложение.

Вот только когда человек начинает говорить, и ты крутишь телефоном влево в право, то нет никакого искажения. Как это реализованно? будто реально человек в бутылке.

Объясните пожалуйста

Comment: Так вроде не особо на этом видео крутят телефоном влево-вправо. Наоборот, стараются держать ровно вроде... Именно когда уже видео начинает воспроизводиться.

Comment: Я к тому что телефон то двигает он, влево в право. И видео плавное охватывает бутылку

Comment: В то время, как он передвигает телефон, работает просто камера телефона вроде. А вот когда уже телефон остановлен, начинает играть AR-видео. Не исключено, что я ошибаюсь, но лично мне так кажется)

Comment: пжлста, посмотрите видео раз 5. Иначе вы не поймете сути данного вопроса. Так как вы не правы.

Comment: Ну это Ar определяет фрейм мб даже фейс детектит, хотя здесь нет смысла, делает вставку поверх. Думаю если руку в этот момент поднести то всё поймёшь. Ничего особенного, но идея прикольная с вином. Мы делали с динамическими фигурами и несколькими фигурами в кадре вот там много проблем